# Sublime Text 2 plugin editorconfig does not work on Mac OSX

Tags: package, sublimetext2, editorconfig

I am used to work with an .editorconfig file at the root of my projects and this one works great with phpstorm. But for some reasons I cannot make it work with Sublime Text 2 on Mac OSX mavericks.

**Sublime 2.0.2 build 2221**

I tried the official **editorconfig** package installation here **https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EditorConfig** with the console and manually but no change after restart of Sublime or even my Mac:

> Sublime just use his default settings for all indentations.

Any idea what I should check ? I am stuck.

Here is my .editorconfig file for info:

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: http://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
charset = utf-8

# 4 space indentation
[*.php]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# 2 space indentation
[**.md]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# 2 space indentation
[**.yaml]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# Tab indentation (no size specified)
[**.js]
indent_style = tab

[**.html]
indent_style = tab

[**.less]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use editor config files. You use sublime settings JSON files. These can be specific to your project, a language, or the whole editor. Go to "Sublime Text" next to the apple symbol (on a Mac, sorry I don't know where this is on PC or Linux), go to preferences and then Settings - Default to see what you can change (it's well commented). See the documentation [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) for all the places you can put settings for different things (like settings for one language or one project).

EDIT: I don't know what plugin you're talking about. You are linking to the install page to the excellent Package Control. Once you have typed that snippet into your console, you can press Command+Shift+P, type insp, hit enter, and search for your plugin to install it. After you install it (I assume you are talking about [this plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EditorConfig)), you'll need to create an .editorconfig file at the highest-level directory for your project.

EDIT 2: I have a feeling your directory structure is wrong. Would you mind showing the directory structure of your project (feel free to change filenames if you feel the need to)? If you're on OS X, you can install a tree command with `brew install tree`. (If you don't have the excellent home brew package manager, go get that.) On Linux or even Windows, this should work out of the box. Anyways, grab the output of that. Otherwise, there could very well be a bug in the plugin, which you can' treacly do anything about unless you have the time to look at the source, hack on it and if your the kind of person who does this kind of thing make a pull request.

Comment: I know those settings, but here my question is about editorconfig sublime plugin. https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2

Comment: Sorry just copy/paste mistake you are right, here the link to editorconfig plugin : https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EditorConfig, I did you command and reinstall it via Package Control but still no working.

Comment: As I told I use the .editorconfig file at the root of my directory and it s working perfectly with phpstorm so it is really a problem with the package. I wrote an issue on the github repo of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime/issues/37), but I think there is an error in that the translate_tabs_to_spaces must be set to **true**, not false.

So, basically, edit your Sublime settings-user file and add `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`
such that it overrides the default settings. I think this is a bug with the plugin as I would have expected EditorConfig to override the Sublime defaults. After all, is this not what you use EditorConfig to do in the first place?

Comment: the issue in github says `translate_tabs_to_spaces must be set to false `